# Thick white lines on mapbox/leaflet js map

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, leaflet, mapbox

I have embedded a map inside a javascript-generated HTML tooltip in d3.js. Functionally, it works, but there are two white horizontal lines that appear at all zoom levels:

[image: zoom level 11]

[image: zoom level 13]

The lines only appear when it's embedded in the popup. If I have it outside the popup, the lines disappear. I've checked my CSS and there's no white lines that would create this (I believe), nor are any parent elements of the `<div id="map></div>` contained in Mapbox's CSS file (which could screw with the formatting).

Any ideas?

Github: [github.com/shaunjacobsen/divvy_savestime](http://github.com/shaunjacobsen/divvy_savestime)
Test site: [sjacobsen.com/testing/2015/bubble-chart.html](http://sjacobsen.com/testing/2015/bubble-chart.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line 155 in your `styles.css`:

```
div.popup img {
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Tiles are images too so that rule affects the images in your tilelayer

Comment: And with that, my project is finished. Thanks for helping me out today!

Comment: No problem, no thanks, you're always welcome this is what SO is for. Acceptance and upvote is more than enough :) Gotta say, really cool what you did with D3 and Leaflet. Looks awesome. Hats off. Looking forward to your next project and problems ;)